# Typescript is not recognising the type of user from express-session

Tags: typescript, mongodb, express, mongoose, typegoose

I'm retrieving the user object from the database and setting it on the express-session:

```
export const postLogin = async (
    request: Request,
    response: Response,
    next: NextFunction
): Promise<void> => {
    try {
        request.session.user = await UserModel.findById('6127bd9d204a47128947a07d').orFail().exec()
        response.redirect('/')
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
}
```

Then I call the Mongoose method `populate()` on the user object to get the cart associated with it:

```
export const getCart = async (
    request: Request,
    response: Response,
    next: NextFunction
): Promise<void> => {
    try {
        const userWithCartProducts = await request.session.user
            .populate('cart.items.productId')
            .execPopulate()
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
}
```

But here I'm getting an error: `TypeError: request.session.user.populate is not a function`

I have defined the custom user type on express-session like following:

```
declare module 'express-session' {
    interface SessionData {
        user?: DocumentType<User>
    }
}
```

As you can see in above definition of `user`, I'm using `DocumentType<User>` because I'm typing my models using [Typegoose](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/docs/guides/quick-start-guide). I'm not sure if this is how it's done for Typegoose.

What am I doing wrong? Any input would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `user` object in the `session` object was fetched by the `MongoDBStore`. The `MongoDBStore` is not aware of the `User` model that is defined in Typegoose, so, when it fetches the data from the session database, it only fetches the raw data, not the methods defined inside the Typegoose model.

So, to fix this, when a new request comes in, after initializing the express-session, in a middleware, we need to fetch the user once from the database and put in on the `request` object like following:

```
app.use(initializeUser)

export const initializeUser = async (request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<void> => {
    try {
        request.user = await User.findById(request.session.user._id).orFail().exec()
        next()
    } catch (error) {
        next(error)
    }
}
```

For Typegoose, define the `User` model on the `Request` as following:

```
declare global {
    declare namespace Express {
        export interface Request {
            user?: DocumentType<User>
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the question, in the `login` route, even though we are storing the `user` object in the `session`, the request dies down there and the session (along with the `user` object) gets saved to the database. But the next time the `request` comes in, the `user` object available in the `session` is retrieved by the `MongoDBStore` which has no knowledge of the `User` Model and the methods defined by the Typegoose. So, this is how we fix that problem. The same solution is also applied in Javascript with Mongoose.